# Consistency of system of linear equations without taking it to echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Establish the conditions under which the equations

$$ax + by + cz = q-r;bx + cy + az = r-p;cx + ay + bz = p-q ,$$

are consistent.
I am aware that by taking the system to echelon can get me the rank of the coefficient matrix and the augmented  matrix. But that turns out to be a very cumbersome process and the terms in the echelon form are very big. Is there other ways to establish the conditions for consistency which are less cumbersome and time consuming?

Comment: Have you tried adding the three equations up together to see what you get?

Comment: @amd It  implies that either a+b+c = 0 or x+y+z= 0. Can you please elaborate on how it can help?

Comment: For what values of $a$, $b$, $c$ does this have a solution?

Comment: @amd It is not provided in the question

Comment: Of course it isn’t. That’s what you’re being asked to determine.

Comment: @amd I did not get why you said " For what values of a, b, c does this have a solution?" when i asked you how adding the three equations can help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38920/discussion-between-ayan-shah-and-amd).

Comment: You asked for a simple way to determine consistency. You now have a single equation that’s equivalent to the original system. Now, all you have to do is determine the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ for which this equation has at least one solution, which is the definition of consistency.

Comment: @amd How am i going to find the values of a, b, c?

Comment: @amd Shall i have to find it by solving the system of given equations? If yes how will i know if the system has atleast one solution?

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with the concept of consistency. It doesn’t look to me like you understood the answers to your other question, either. Try looking at it from the other direction: are there any values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ for which the combined equations has *no* solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand sides of the three equations suggest that adding them all together might be fruitful. When you do this, you get, after a little bit of fiddling, $$(a+b+c)(x+y+z)=0.$$ This equation can be satisfied for any values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, so the original system is also consistent for all values of these parameters, as well as all values of $p$ and $q$, since the latter don’t appear in this equation at all.

Another approach is to use Cramer’s rule, just as in an answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1759387/265466). $$\det\pmatrix{a&b&c\\b&c&a\\c&a&b}=3abc-(a^3+b^3+c^3).$$ This is equal to zero when $a+b+c=0$, so there are two cases to consider. If $a+b+c\ne 0$, there is a unique solution to this system of equations for any values of $p$ and $q$. If it’s zero, you’ll need to look a little more closely to determine consistency.

One way to proceed in that case is to substitute $c=-a-b$ in the augmented matrix of the system and row-reduce. The computation is a bit messy, but not as bad a row-reducing the original augmented matrix. The system is consistent (thought indeterminate) iff all of the zero rows on the left (unaugmented) side of the rref have zeros in the right-hand column. (You’ll end up with denominators of $a^2+ab+b^2$, but that can’t be zero.) Another way to go is to perform this substitution in the three equations, and then add them together as in the first part of this answer. You end up with $0=0$, which is obviously consistent.